# Take the frequency of each digit in a randomly generated number with while loops and if statements

Tags: java

This is in java. I am trying to write a method that randomly generates a number 1000000 - 2000000, then takes the frequency of each digit. We cannot use arrays or for loops.

For example, if the number is 1880500, the output would be:
(1, 1), (8, 2), (5, 1), (0, 3).

However, my output looks like this: (1, 1), (8, 2), (8, 1), (0, 3), (0, 2), (5, 1), (0, 1).

So my problem is that I don't know how to stop a digit from printing twice if that digit was already printed. Thanks

This is my code for the method:

```
      int num = 1000000 + (int)(Math.random() * (2000000 - 1000000 + 1));
      System.out.println("The generated number is: " + num);
      int oneDigit = num % 10;

      while (num > 0) {
         int oneDigitCount = 0;
         int num2 = num;
         while (num2 > 0) {
            if (num2 % 10 == oneDigit) {
               oneDigitCount++;
            }
            num2 /= 10;
         }
         if (num < 10 && oneDigit != newDigit) {
            System.out.printf("(%d, %d)", oneDigit, oneDigitCount);
         }
         else {
         System.out.printf("(%d, %d), ", oneDigit, oneDigitCount);
         }
         num /= 10;
         oneDigit = num % 10;
```

Comment: Can you use maps ?

Comment: no, just while loops and if statements

Answer (score 0):

You're currently parsing your number *n* times, where *n* is the number of digits.  So, if the number is 1880500, you're counting the number of 0's in 1880500, then you're counting the number of 0's in 188050, then you're counting the number of 5's in 18805, then the number of 0's in 1880, etc.

Since you apparently can't use arrays, maps, or for loops, we need a slightly different approach.  Fortunately, since we're dealing with a known set of digits, we can kind of invert the logic here.  Instead of getting the digits from the number itself (which is ultimately what's causing the duplication), we can use a while loop to loop through the digits 0 - 9, and look for them in the original number.

```
    int num = 1000000 + (int) (Math.random() * (2000000 - 1000000 + 1));
    System.out.println("The generated number is: " + num);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        int count = 0;
        int temp = num;
        while (temp > 0) {
            int digit = temp % 10;
            if (digit == i) {
                count++;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }

        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.printf("(%d, %d), ", i, count);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

You'll notice that this is essentially identical to a for loop.  For the most part, loops are loops, and the distinction between while and for loops is just a convenience.

Comment: Thank you for answering but we can't use arrays or for loops

Comment: If you have serious restriction about which data structures you can and can't use, you really should include that information in your original question.

Comment: i did say i cannot use arrays or for loops in the original question

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I must have missed that.  And you also can't use Maps?  So you're restricted only to if-statements and while-loops?

Comment: Check out the update to my answer.  I've removed everything but while loops and if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your random number to a String, we are able to get the character in that string and count how many times the character appears then remove it from the string. Loop through the string until there are no characters left.

```
public void printFrequency(int number) {
    //convert the number to a string
    String numString = String.valueOf(number);

    //loop until the string length is replaced
    while (numString.length() > 0) {
        // get the first "character" in the string
        String char1 = String.valueOf(numString.charAt(0));

        //check to see how many of the characters were replaced with empty
        int count = numString.length() - numString.replaceAll(char1, "").length();

        //print
        System.out.println(String.format("(%s, %d)", char1, count));

        //trim the string
        numString = numString.replaceAll(char1, "");   
    }
}
```

Output

```
(1, 1)
(8, 2)
(0, 3)
(5, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, in general, it's better to create a method and retrieve a `String` as a result instead of using `System.out`. In case you have restrictions, just be simple:

```
public static String calc(int num) {
    int zero = 0;
    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    int four = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int six = 0;
    int seven = 0;
    int eight = 0;
    int nine = 0;

    while (num > 0) {
        int n = num % 10;

        if (n == 0)
            zero++;
        else if (n == 1)
            one++;
        else if (n == 2)
            two++;
        else if (n == 3)
            three++;
        else if (n == 4)
            four++;
        else if (n == 5)
            five++;
        else if (n == 6)
            six++;
        else if (n == 7)
            seven++;
        else if (n == 8)
            eight++;
        else
            nine++;

        num /= 10;
    }

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    if (zero > 0)
        buf.append("(0,").append(zero).append("),");
    if (one > 0)
        buf.append("(1,").append(one).append("),");
    if (two > 0)
        buf.append("(2,").append(two).append("),");
    if (three > 0)
        buf.append("(3,").append(three).append("),");
    if (four > 0)
        buf.append("(4,").append(four).append("),");
    if (five > 0)
        buf.append("(5,").append(five).append("),");
    if (six > 0)
        buf.append("(6,").append(six).append("),");
    if (seven > 0)
        buf.append("(7,").append(seven).append("),");
    if (eight > 0)
        buf.append("(8,").append(eight).append("),");
    if (nine > 0)
        buf.append("(9,").append(nine).append("),");

    if (buf.length() > 0)
        buf.setLength(buf.length() - 1);

    return buf.toString();
}
```

---

**Demo.** Buy the way, you have a sorted result.

```
System.out.println(calc(1880500));  // (0,3),(1,1),(5,1),(8,2)
```